# insert current time into mongo using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to store a current time in specific format, when new document where created.
Here is the part of the code that call's not working method:

```
    dbm = AccountsDB()
    dbm.store_info(user_info)
```

And here is the actual AccountsDB() class:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7

import pymongo
import datetime
import time

class AccountsDB():
    def store_info(self, user_info=None):
        try:
            conn = pymongo.Connection('localhost', 27017)
            db_name = 'accountsdb'
            coll_name = 'user_info'

            db = conn[db_name]
            coll = db[coll_name]
            print "Successfully connected to '%s'" % db_name

            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            if user_info is not None:
                now = datetime.datetime.now()
                ''' 
                This is not Working...

                created_time = {
                    'created_time': {
                        'day': now.day,
                        'month': now.month,
                        'year': now.year,
                        'hour': now.hour,
                        'minute': now.minute,
                        'second': now.second,
                        'microsecond': now.microsecond
                    }
                }
                user_info.append(created_time)
                '''
                print user_info
                coll.insert(user_info)
            else:
                print 'No user_info'
            print "Data where stored in database"
        except:
            print "Some Error Occured"
```

I want  document looks something like this:

```
> db.user_info.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50d8ded1bdbff3401c252f1a"),
    "ip" : "24.xx.xx.xx",
    "region_code" : "MA",
    "region_name" : "Massachusetts",
    "secret_answer2" : "Mercedes",
    "l_name" : "Flores",
    "f_name" : "Jacob",
    "country_name" : "United States",
        // I want to add next objects to the document
        'created_time': {
            'day': 10,
            'month': 11,
            'year': 12,
            'hour': 11,
            'minute': 11,
            'second': 22,
            'microsecond': 1234
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more information on why this code is not working or what about it is not working?  I just tried something very similar as a test and the document (along with the datetime in the format you desired) was inserted perfectly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like you want python code to pass the current time to mongo in a pymongo call. You this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 24, 18, 33, 46, 266943)
```

Complete code looks like this:

```
import pymongo
from datetime import datetime

class AccountsDB():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def store_info(self, user_info=None):
        try:
            conn = pymongo.Connection('localhost', 27017)
            db_name = 'accountsdb'
            coll_name = 'user_info'
            db = conn[db_name]
            coll = db[coll_name]
            print "Successfully connected to '%s'" % db_name
            if user_info is not None:
                user_info['created_time'] = datetime.now()
                print user_info
                coll.insert(user_info)
            else:
                print 'No user_info'
            print "Data where stored in database"
        except:
            print "Some Error Occured"

a = AccountsDB()
a.store_info({})
```

Comment: Is there a way to use mongod's idea of the current time, so that you don't have to worry about clock sync with multiple mongo clients running on different systems?

Comment: @rakslice: I am not sure how that would work. You have to assign a python data type to the dictionary item but you would then have to have that execute in the context of mongodb.

Comment: It is important to use utcnow() and not now(), as you'll otherwise end up inserting a local time, as mentioned in kommradHomer's answer.

Answer (score 8):

pymongo suggests you should simply use `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`

> For example, the following code stores the current UTC date and time
>   into MongoDB:
>
> `>>> result = db.objects.insert_one( ...     {"last_modified": datetime.datetime.utcnow()})`
>
> Always use datetime.datetime.utcnow(), which returns the current time in UTC, instead of `datetime.datetime.now()`, which returns the current local time. Avoid
>   doing this:
>
> `>>> result = db.objects.insert_one( ...     {"last_modified": datetime.datetime.now()})`

[pymongo datetimes](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/datetimes.html)

Comment: Broken url. Use this https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/datetimes.html